# Using multiple beacons to articulate accurate user location

Tags: ios, bluetooth, sensors, iot

Is it possible to find an accurate position of a person in a room using multiple Bluetooth beacons set up around the room through proximity detection? I've done some research and it says it is difficult to detect proximity with a Bluetooth sensor but can I overcome this through using multiple Bluetooth beacons? The point is you can use multiple Bluetooth beacons to triangulate positions and we'll be developing an iOS app that dictates the user (blind or disabled) where obstacles are. I'm wondering if this idea is doable and am curious how I can achieve accurate proximity sensing with Bluetooth beacons.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you will find it difficult to get a position more accurate than +/- 5-10m so it probably won't work for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who thinks of this idea in the future:

Bluetooth really isn't ideal but there can be other ways such as using
other types of sensors.